# Regex for escaping path separator in url

Tags: python, regex, django

I have a url pattern:   "somepath/email/". I don't want to write a regex for matching email instead I want anything which isn't a path separator to match email.

Please suggest a regex for this. I am using Python and the url is for a Django application, So any library function will also be helpful but I will prefer a regex.

Comment: By path separator I mean that it should not be "/" or "\". It should just match the email without caring about special characters. Main motto is not to write a complex regex for matching email.

Comment: you could also simply use this `r'something/(?P<email>[^/\\]+)'` which will match things more closely resembling an email

Comment: If you need it for breadcrumb, then be aware, that there are much better ways of doing it in Django.

Comment: @vlad-ardelean Thanks ! This was something I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex `[^/\\]+` is a negative character class with a `+` quantifier and matches any number of characters that are not a `/` or `\\`

**Code sample:**

```
match = re.search("[^/\\]+", subject)
if match:
    result = match.group()
else:
    result = ""
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that it should also not be "\".

Comment: @bitgeeky Modified the regex, let me know if this is what you're looking for. :)

Comment: Thanks, this was something I was looking for r'something/(?P<email>[^/\\]+)'

Comment: @bitgeeky You're very welcome, have a great weekend.